# Is there the need for both package.swift and package.resolved?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm new to Swift Package Manager but I pulled a project from git with different people working on it and I can't find the **package.swift** in it. On a further check, I realized **package.resolved** was in there.

1. Do the two perform the same role?
2. When I build, I don't see a Sources folder, Even though I see the Packages in Xcode. Is that normal?
3. New sub packages eg. (FirebaseAuth from Firebase) that I now add to the dependencies are not available for use in the project. Seeing "No such module" errors

Comment: 1. No, not at all. The first one is the configuration of the package that you edit, the second one is created when building the package

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you. So if it came with package.resolved and not package.swift, how do I build the packages from package.resolved? Or do I have to create a new package.swift? How does that work?

Answer (score 2):

For the first question:

It's like `Podfile` & `Podfile.lock` for instance (and many other dependency managers).

The `Package.swift` let you tell what you need.
The `Package.resolved` let you know what was downloaded/used.

The `Package.swift` is the "command", "developer settings", in this case it's "Swift code", and the other one is just a "text file", a manifest, a written record of what is really used.

In the `Package.swift` you might need a `PackageA`. But `PackageA` might need `SubpackageB`. But it would be a pain to add manually all the subpackages. At a higher level, you don't need to know them.
In the `Package.resolved` there are written there.

You might specify a version, or a minimum version for a Package: like "1.0.0" up to "1.xx.xx", to get the fixes/revisions when updating the dependencies.
In the `Package.resolved` you have the exact versions that have been downloaded/used.
This allow you, if you don't do an update, to recover the exact same version of the packages.
For instance, if you have the "1.0.0", there is a "1.1.0" available that fix an issue, you might want to be on that specific version "1.0.0" to reproduce the issue, or if the "1.1.0" introduces a new bug, you want to keep that 1.1.0, and not perform an update until otherwise. And when you buil to release the App, you keep using the same version of the packages, the one you used/tested with (until there is a manual update).